# Anchor test fails

Tags: anchor, testing, anchor-test

I have this function :

```
pub fn sign_up(ctx: Context<SignUp> , user_name: String , phone: String , email: String) -> Result<()> {// Code is here}
```

And inside it i have :

```
        // Email format validation check
    if !email.is_empty() {

        // email length check
        if email.len() > 100 {
                        // Throwing an error
        return Err(error!(Errors::EmailLengthExceeded));
        }

        let re = Regex::new(r"^([a-z0-9_+]([a-z0-9_+.]*[a-z0-9_+])?)@([a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6})").unwrap();
        let is_email_valid: bool = re.is_match(&email);
        if is_email_valid == false {
            return Err(error!(Errors::InvalidEmailAddress));
        }
    }
```

And in the tests i have :

```
        await program.rpc.signUp("reasje", "09146979106", "", {
        accounts: {
            user: user.publicKey,
            authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            clock: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
        },
        signers: [user],
    });
```

The test fails with this error message:

`Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction`

Note that I have send the email as "" which is empty but I don't how the `if !email.is_empty()` evaluates true the proof for that is when i comment the Regex code the error goes away .

So i have two questions :

1. Why `if !email.is_empty()` is true ?
2. Why the regex code throws error ?

Comment: Could you put the relevant code in the solana playground and share a link? beta.solpg.io

Comment: @CallumM Of course https://beta.solpg.io/62e7b284f6273245aca4f619 if you have any improvements please let me know .

Comment: Can you try skipping the simulation and see what error is actually coming up? `program.rpc.` is deprecated so I'd suggest this syntax: `program.methods.signUp(...).accounts(...).signers(...).rpc({ skipPreflight: true })` that should also skip simulation

Comment: @sohrab I did what you said and this is the error output which is similar to the previous one : `     Error: Raw transaction 5VRd9SyVpBa3FaM6zyLaL9pQNRpvAJ4ng21yfj6TzX5H7qamsLAaD8Lj3pHYdzNdtAiai2So9ppindybjCunGCvK failed ({"err":{"InstructionError":[0,"InvalidAccountData"]}})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very likely a dependency issue. A lot of crates will be incompatible with the Solana runtime, especially if they depend on the rand crate. Solana doesn't allow randomness on-chain. If you really want to do this particular check you'll have to do it in the client.

Comment: Is there any way to find out which crates do have problems with Solana runtime and which ones i can use ?

Comment: I don't know if there's any straightforward way to know until you try. What I do know is that any crate that depends on rand directly or indirectly won't compile. The issue is that many crates do in some way.